# If OR with RIGHT in Excel

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

This seems simple, but evidently incorrect. Have any ideas?

**The data:**
Cell J5 value is simply this URL:

www.url.com/at/

**The logic:** Check if cell J5 ends in "/at/" or if it ends in "de/", value if true for either one of those is 1, value if false for both is zero.

Here's the function I'm trying out:

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(J5,4)=“/at/"),(RIGHT(J5,3)=“de/"),"1","0")
```

My result is #NAME?

Comment: your link to URL is not working

Comment: You closed the OR too soon, and you used this “ instead of ". =IF(OR(RIGHT(J5,4)="/at/",RIGHT(J5,3)="de/"),"1","0")

Comment: Additionally, I'm trying to figure out a similar one that checks for 3 things instead of two. If ends J6 ends in /au/ or en/ or com/

Comment: @marco-getrost that's it! THANK YOU

Comment: You can just include it in the OR part like this: 
=IF(OR(RIGHT(J6,4)="/au/",RIGHT(J6,3)="en/",RIGHT(J6,4)="com/"),"1","0")

Answer (score 1):

The double bracket characters are incorrect (before the /at and before the de/).  Make sure you use "" around string literals.  Secondly the closing bracket is not required after the first RIGHT and does not need open bracket before the second right.  With these corrections the formula becomes:

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(J5,4)="/at/",RIGHT(J5,3)="de/"),"1","0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command has incorrect parenthesis.

Your command:

`IF(OR(RIGHT(J5,4)=“/at/"),(RIGHT(J5,3)=“de/"),"1","0")`

**OR(RIGHT(J5,4)="/at/")** is the cause of output **#NAME** because OR in this case has only one operand.

You should not close the parenthesis here and should close it after the second operand.

Try:

> IF(OR(RIGHT(J5,4)=“/at/",RIGHT(J5,3)=“de/"),"1","0")

[image: Screenshot of the test.]

Comment: Fantastic. I'm glad it was that simple - thank yu :)

Comment: @pnuts - care to elaborate?

Comment: @pnuts I tested before answering it. I tested it again. It works. I am looking for a way to attach screenshot for you.